# C# MVC Ajax post with instant user text feedback while server is processing

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, ajaxform

I'm trying to give my users some sort of text feedback while the server is busy processing my ajax request.

Some of my functions take some time to run. For example my form post does the following:

- Gets a list of users.
- Gets a list of jobs linked to users.
- Gets all notifications linked to users.
- Gets all candidates linked to users.
- Generates all candidate emails.
- Sends all candidate emails.

so instead of showing a static ajax loader i would like that before each one of the above mentioned operations is executed i would like to send feedback to the html page informing the user what operation is currently taking place.

Eg. Generating User List > Obtaining notifications > Obtaining Candidates > Sending Emails.

I am currently posting the form with **jquery.form.js**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RejectApplicant", "Application", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @id = "RejectApplicantForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    // Token
    // all required input fields here
}

 $(function () {

            $('#RejectApplicantForm').ajaxForm({
                beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
                    //  return Validate()
                },
                complete: function (result) {

                    // get results
                }
            });

        });
```

any ideas?

Comment: You said you were trying to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: Looked at HttpMessages, tried setting ViewBags with the messages, but i cant get the html or the ajax to read the variables i set until the entire action is finished running.

Comment: Why not make each long-running function a separate method and just make a series of AJAX calls?

Comment: That does not seems like a very good idea considering that i am making 1 form post, in the back end there is some multi-threading happening and i don't want to break any sort of parallelism by breaking apart into individual calls. and in some cases new operations depend on results of a previous operation.